# Does exception handling in Clarion exist?

Tags: error-handling, clarion

Does Clarion 8 offer anything for exception handling?  I know [as of Clarion 5 there was no support](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/comp.lang.clarion/exception%2420handling%2420/comp.lang.clarion/ITD2HfrJ0tY/Fa2qNR0wRxQJ) for things like `try / catch` but that was released almost 10 years ago.  I can't seem to find any info on how to recover from exceptions in C6 to C8 unless I was using Clarion# (aka Clarion.NET) which I'm not.  If there's definitely nothing like `try / catch`, are there any tricks or hacks that can be used to not have a program crash when an exception is thrown even if it goes unhandled?

If it helps, I'm using version 8.0.0.8778.

**EDIT 1:**

Here is some sample code for a basic program that should supposedly illustrate the feature `PROP:LastChanceHook`, however, I can't get it to work.  When I run this program, I see the first message "Start", but then nothing happens.  I've tried returning 0 or 1 from `Hook` but that hasn't made a difference either.  Every time I run this, I have to go onto the Task Manager and end the process for the program because it's not being killed.

```
PROGRAM
    INCLUDE('CWEXCPT.INT'), ONCE
    MAP
        Hook(*ICWExceptionInfo), LONG
        Test(LONG,LONG)
    END
    CODE
        MESSAGE('[Sample] Start')
        SYSTEM{PROP:LastChanceHook} = ADDRESS(Hook)
        Test(10, 0) ! Intentionally causes an exception
        MESSAGE('[Sample] After Test')
        RETURN ! Tried removing this, no difference

Hook PROCEDURE(*ICWExceptionInfo info)
    CODE
        MESSAGE('[Sample] Start Hook')
        IF info &= NULL THEN RETURN 0 END
        Message('An exception!')
        RETURN 1 ! 0 = don't kill, anything > 0 = tell RTL to kill the thread

Test PROCEDURE (LONG a, LONG b)
    CODE
        a %= b
```

Comment: I know that Clarion.NET supports exception handling.

Comment: @JustinSkiles - I mentioned I'm not using that, just straight Clarion 8. Clarion# is synonymous with Clarion.NET right?

Comment: @JustinSkiles - no problem. Thanks for commenting. If you ever do find out a way, don't forget about this post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take a look at prop:LastChanceHook in the help. It may provide enough function for your needs.

In other cases, the info at this link might also be useful: 
http://clarionsharp.com/blog/tracking-down-those-pesky-gpfs/

In the next public build of C8 (it's presently Sept 27, 2012), the buttons on that exception display (shown at the link above) can be customized a bit.

Comment: +1 just for responding to a Clarion question.  I'll try it out as soon as I can get the next build of C8.  If it truly helps, at that point I'll post my solution and mark you as answered.

Comment: I tried PROP:LastChanceHook but I can't seem to get it to work.  I updated my original question to show a sample program that doesn't seem to work for me.  If you've got any thoughts on it, I'd really appreciate your input.

Comment: I tried the example in the help for 9.0.9632 and it didnt work either. Entered their source and the results as PTSS 39599.

Comment: I just updated the question, but FWIW I'm running 8.0.0.8778.

Comment: I marked this as answered because I've heard from a few other Clarion devs that this should work, but doesn't in newer builds of Clarion. Supposedly SV is working on some sort of fix.  Thanks again for finding this.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Yes, I filed a bug report for it and they accepted it. Now we just wait for the fix:)